# React: how to load and render external html file?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux

I building a small blog app using React and Redux. 
The blog show Posts page with title, author, tags and description of a post. When clicking on title or "read more" button, I want to load and render an HTML file with corresponding post from a local project's data folder with all the posts.

Redux is managing the state of the blog, loading initial posts.json file with 8 different posts, including htmlPath for the corresponding html file in the data folder.

Comment: Do you want to render the external html static and "as is" or is there any need to "parse" it somehow or make it interact with React (e.g component states) somehow?

Comment: Just render it, lets say I click on post's title "Hello World" and get all the post rendered from file hello-world.html

Comment: People will be pulling their hair at this one. It does not sound right. However, one starts to build app in React, expecting wonders, then gets to a point where one wants to do something that was easy, simple, unambiguous, straightforward to do with PHP.

Answer (score 30):

The way I see it is that you have 2 problems to solve here. The first is how to set the `innerHTML` of an element in React. The other is how to get a specific HTML to render depending on a given variable (e.g the current route, the input of a textfield, etc).

### 1. Setting the `innerHTML` of an element

You can do this with the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` prop. As the name suggests it sets the `innerHTML` of the said element to whatever you specify... and yes, the "dangerously" is accurate as it's intended to make you think twice before using this feature.

The [**Official Documentation**](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html) reads as follows:

> Improper use of the innerHTML can open you up to a cross-site scripting (XSS) attack. Sanitizing user input for display is notoriously error-prone, and failure to properly sanitize is one of the leading causes of web vulnerabilities on the internet.

Check out this [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/8ntjuzqc/) or the snippet below.

```js
var Demo = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {showExternalHTML: false};
  },
  
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.toggleExternalHTML}>Toggle Html</button>
        {this.state.showExternalHTML ? <div>
          <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.createMarkup()} ></div>
        </div> : null}
      </div>
    );
  },
  
  toggleExternalHTML: function() {
    this.setState({showExternalHTML: !this.state.showExternalHTML});
  },
  
  createMarkup: function() { 
    return {__html: '<div class="ext">Hello!</div>'};
  }

});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Demo />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```css
.ext {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

---

### 2. Fetching the HTML from an external source

Note that the above example does not actually get the HTML from an external file, but is entered directly as a string.

One simple way to do dynamically fetch a choose a specific file would be to let your backend (e.g php) read the file from a local folder, parse the text, and send it back through an AJAX request.

## Example

```
//Your React component
fetchExternalHTML: function(fileName) {
  Ajax.getJSON('/myAPI/getExternalHTML/' + fileName).then(
    response => {
      this.setState({
        extHTML: response
      });
    }, err => {
      //handle your error here
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Is there a safe and reccommended alternative to loading external HTML?

Comment: @colecmc, not sure what you mean. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: So I've got some html as a string, retrieved through a fetch call. With vanillaJS I would use `innerHTML` or `insertAdjacentHTML()` but with React, I'm not sure of the best approach. I'm considering turning the string to JSON and then adding components by looping through JSON.

Comment: @colecmc, did you try method 1 above?

Comment: I will need to tweak my setup to make it work but I will give it a try. Thanks a million @Chris

Comment: using innerHTML is not safe.

Comment: @paddotk, can you elaborate?

Comment: @Chris innerHTML is prone to code injection. The React team decided to call this property (within React) `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` as a hint to the risk of using it. Read this bit for some further explanation: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Comment: @paddotk, my answer does involve the use of `innerHTML` at all. The first option uses `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` and I even explain of what it is and what it does. You are explaining to me what I already explained in my answer :P Not trying to be brash or anything, but did you read my whole answer?

Comment: It's one of two suggestions you give so it does involve (dangerouslySet)innerHTML..? I think it's only fair and necessary to mention that it's not safe.

Comment: @paddotk, I agree but I do mention the *potential* risk of using it. What I am trying to understand is why it got downvoted. The risks are well emphasized in my answer.

Comment: @Chris Sorry about that, I guess I shouldn't be on stackoverflow so late in the evening :p. I did apparently not read it all the way through and thus wanna undo my downvote, however SO says my vote is locked :( Apologies!

Comment: @paddotk No worries. You got me really confused there for a while :P

Answer (score 18):

While Chris's answer was good, some more digging was required to make it work. Here are the steps that you need to take:

Add html loader to your project:

```
npm i -D html-loader
```

Add the following rule to your webpack.config file:

```
{
  test: /\.(html)$/,
  use: {
    loader: 'html-loader',
    options: {
      attrs: [':data-src']
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can import your html file as follow:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Page from './test.html';
var htmlDoc = {__html: Page};

export default class Doc extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  render(){
     return (<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={htmlDoc} />)
}}
```

Comment: I have done it EXACTLY as you described, but I get a string for the Page like "samples/myHtmlCode.html"

Comment: Oh wait... I had the .html files in a test for some other loader as well. now it works

Comment: this doesn't work for fetching html from the server, it only builds your webpack project with the html source as a data url (who would want to do this?)

Comment: @r3wt and here i am again 1 year later to do exactly what i argued against above...

Comment: It does not like the data-src : ValidationError: Invalid options object. HTML Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'attrs'

Comment: Care to elaborate how to "Add the following rule to your webpack.config file" ? By default I don't even have a webpack.config file from create-react-app

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the external pages to include are unknown at compile time of your app, and you don't need the app and the page to be able to interact (like, the page is a standalone HTML, for example rendered using a Markdown engine), `iframe` HTML element could do the job well. (More at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe ).

Syntax is as follows :

```
<iframe src="link/to/your/html/page.html"></iframe>
```

And... Voilà, your page is displayed in the `iframe`.

It has some advantages :

- It is super simple
- It creates a new navigation context and thus "isolates" the external page from the app, making it relatively safe to use when displaying user-submitted content, at least in comparison to direct inclusion.

And some drawbacks :

- Because of isolation, the CSS of your app will not be applied to the page, you have to include it manually in the page.
- Likewise, you can't interact with page DOM from app. Nor the opposite.
- Having multiple navigation contexts can be costly in comparison to direct inclusion in the app. This isn't a problem for a single page, but if you have hundredth of posts, you'll likely have to make sure that not all of their external pages are displayed at the same time (for example, make is so that only `view more` can be applied at a time.
- Links within the page will not be affected by the eventual link resolution of your app. This can force you to maintain two different conventions when it comes to links and paths : one for the app, one for the pages.

Answer (score 0):

If you really sure, get the post contents to frontend how you like from file system with server code, and show it in React component with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`:

```
function createMarkup() { 
    return {__html: 'First &middot; Second'}; 
};

<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />
```

More in docs: https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html

Comment: I know about dangerouslySet, the thing I cant accomplish is when clicked on link, how to go with the path I have in store ../../data/posts/html/[name].html and load the content of the file into the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [react-templates](https://wix.github.io/react-templates/). This is 'the' best available. You can have your template as an external file and can load it whenever you want and it'll render like charm with all the React API available.

Hope it helps.