# How to render html file in react

Tags: reactjs

I need to load  HTML file (home) into home JavaScript file using react. I don't know how to load my file.Please help me on this. I have used below code for load in JS file

```
import React from 'react';
import template  from '../home/home.html';
const Home = () => {
    return (
      template()
    );
}
```

export default Home;

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html React is using jsx however if you want to store dom element inside a tag you could stringify it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React: how to load and render external html file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40108843/react-how-to-load-and-render-external-html-file)

Comment: this is an idea for webpack loader that loads html as a react component, not sure it's useful though