# Mix landing page with react app (create-react-app)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

What are the best practices for "integrating" a React app into an existing HTML landing page?

For example, I have a marketing page on mypage.com/ and would like to use the react app on mypage.com/app only.

What I tried is to use react router and use the dangerouslySetInnerHTML function to include the HTML page but for this case I need to use a html-loader and I use react-scripts instead of the webpack.config so I think it is not possible to add the loader. Isn't it?

```
<Router>
  <Route path="/" exact component={Landingpage} />
  <Route path="/app" exact component={App} />
</Router>
```

```
/* Landingpage */
return () {
  <div ... dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html }} />
}
```

I tried the following but I don't have the webpack.config because I use react-scripts.
[React: how to load and render external html file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40108843/react-how-to-load-and-render-external-html-file)

What I want is to call yarn build and receive the finished application.
Do you have any suggestions how I can reach that?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Do you have mypage.com/app page as html?

Comment: Not at the moment. I call yarn build and get an index.html with the react application. That's the problem. Edit: I mean I have the production html (the application) as index.html in the build folder.

Comment: Then maybe create app.html and add reference from index.html(anchor tag) and in script of app.html add react js code?

Comment: You mean I can create the app.html in the public folder instead (or additionally) of the existing index.html (with the "root" id element)?

Comment: yeah just add app.html file, add link to it and it will show `mypage.com/app.html`. Try that first. After you can add script with react code

Comment: But I want to use yarn run start and this means that the index.js wants to render the react app to the "root" element (index.js from package.json is executed on page load). I did this but now i get the error that there is no "root" id - element in the index.html. That's correct because this element is in the app.html..  become desperate :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Bad news**
You can't do that with default configuration of [create-react-app](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/)

**Good News**
It is possible with *eject*.

1. `npm run eject`
2. Add `app.html` and add link to it from `index.html`
3. inside `config/paths.js` change line `appHtml: resolveApp('public/app.html')` to

```js
...
appHtml: resolveApp('public/app.html'),
...
```

4. `config/webpack.config.js` change to

```
{
  filename: 'app.html', // Add this line
  inject: true,
  template: paths.appHtml
},
```

5. Configure `react-router` if exists, accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! Sounds good for me. The new index.html works but when I go to mypage.com/app.html there is no content. The root-Element contains an empty div only. Are there some other things I have to configure? Edit: Do I have to configure react-router? In index.js the 'App' i import is undefined...

Comment: I'll do it with one index.html and add two routers ( "/" and "/app") - That is the easiest way I think. Thanks!

Comment: You need to copy content of index.html to app.html.

Comment: Hey, it's worked well so far - thanks! The only problem I have now is that my reaction routers are not working.... 
I have three routers: /app.html, /home and /next
When I call /app.html, my app.html component is rendered, so to speak. However, if I change the URL to /home, the content from the landing page will be displayed. Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: Can I ask a question, do you have backend? And are you managing it?

Comment: I don‘t manage a backend, I deploy it to netlify, run the yarn build command and that‘s it.

Comment: I want to suggest just start new app(create-react-app). Setup you route. And transform you landing page to react one. I know it will take time. But it will payoff. Especially if there is not many js code in landing page.

Comment: Okay there is a lot of javascript code for the landingpage.. Is there a way to move the react app to domain.com/app/index.htm or is it the same? I mean I can include the html via the dangerouslySetInnerHtml React function but then the javascript will not be executed... Is there a way to execute the javascript for the landingpage after I insert it via dangerouslySetInnerHtml? That would be cool!

Comment: Yeah you cannot actually, only if you implement them. So my suggestion instead of trying to insert landing page to react app, because there will be a lot of issue. Just create component as you landing page, this is only advice I can suggest.