# How to render raw HTML content to React pass via props?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to pass a variable in return of a component. Here is my code:

```
const Obj = (props) => {

    let { propId } = useParams();
    
    const [data, setData] = useState({ course: [] });

    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            const result = await axios.get(
                'http://example.com/api/v1/' + propId
            ).catch(err => {
                console.error(err);
            });
            setData(result.data);
        })();
    }, [propId]);
    
    return (
        <Fragment key={propId}>
            <div>
                {data.htmlContent}
            </div>
        </Fragment>
    );
};

export default Obj;
```

At here it shows this:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
```

How can I insert this html content to main content?

Comment: I actually get <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>

Comment: you passing html , it's not JSX.
when you create html tags on react, it's actually a react elements, where is different from the html you get from the request. you need to convert it to a react element

Comment: Then, how can I convert this to JSX?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40108843/react-how-to-load-and-render-external-html-file

Comment: you can use "html-to-react" library https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-react

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) attribute :

```
 <Fragment key={propId}>
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ { __html: data.htmlContent}} >
           
            </div>
        </Fragment>
```