# is it possible to load another website page on my react website?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

is it possible to load another website page on my website? I google and iframe is one of the ways, are there any other ways?

Comment: Is the page you want to load part of your site? Or a different site?

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40108843/react-how-to-load-and-render-external-html-file

Comment: another website from another domain

Comment: Add an [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe).