# How to load external static HTML page with script tags in react?

Tags: html, reactjs

I want to load a static html file which has script tags in it as a react component. I tried [html-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/html-loader/) approach but this is converting the html file to a string but that string is not correctly rendered in the react DOM.

Below is my Sample html file.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.16.1/vis.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.16.1/vis-network.min.js"> </script>
<center>
<h1>Test</h1>
</center>

<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/vis/dist/vis.min.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../node_modules/vis/dist/vis.js"> </script>-->

<style type="text/css">

        #mynetwork {
            width: 900;
            height: 450;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            border: 1px solid lightgray;
            position: relative;
            float: left;
        }  
</style>

</head>

<body>
<div id = "mynetwork"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    // initialize global variables.
    var edges;
    var nodes;
    var network; 
    var container;
    var options, data;

    
    // This method is responsible for drawing the graph, returns the drawn network
    function drawGraph() {
        var container = document.getElementById('mynetwork');
       
        // parsing and collecting nodes and edges from the python
        nodes = new vis.DataSet([{"id": 0, "label": 0, "shape": "dot", "size": 5}, {"id": 17, "label": 17, "shape": "dot", "size": 5}, {"id": 56, "label": 56, "shape": "dot", "size": 5}, {"id": 65, "label": 65, "shape": "dot", "size": 5}, {"id": 68, "label": 68, "shape": "dot", "size": 5}]);
        edges = new vis.DataSet([{"from": 0, "to": 17, "weight": 10.1990327835083}, {"from": 0, "to": 56, "weight": 11.132073402404785}, {"from": 0, "to": 65, "weight": 11.344696998596191}, {"from": 0, "to": 68, "weight": 10.370659828186035}, {"from": 0, "to": 76, "weight": 11.320157051086426}, {"from": 0, "to": 82, "weight": 10.778494834899902}, {"from": 0, "to": 94, "weight": 11.241415977478027}]);

        // adding nodes and edges to the graph
        data = {nodes: nodes, edges: edges};

        var options = {
    "configure": {
        "enabled": false
    },
    "edges": {
        "color": {
            "inherit": true
        },
        "smooth": {
            "enabled": false,
            "type": "continuous"
        }
    },
    "interaction": {
        "dragNodes": true,
        "hideEdgesOnDrag": false,
        "hideNodesOnDrag": false
    },
    "physics": {
        "enabled": true,
        "stabilization": {
            "enabled": true,
            "fit": true,
            "iterations": 1000,
            "onlyDynamicEdges": false,
            "updateInterval": 50
        }
    }
};
        network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
        return network;

    }

    drawGraph();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In webconfig.js I had added the below code

```
    {
    test: /\.html$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: {loader: 'html-loader'}
    },
```

This is how i am rendering in react

```
import Page from "./Sample.html";
var htmlDoc = { __html: Page };
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={htmlDoc} />
```

The problem is it is not showing the graph. But i can see the `<h1>` Tag populated on top of the page but not the graph.

How can resolve this issue?

Any help is appreciated
Thanks

Comment: 30000 chars - next time try a [mcve] ;)

Comment: @mplungjan updated the sample html to less chars.

Answer (score 0):

you can use dangerouslySetInnerHTM prop. this question is already answered on stackoverflow. check it out [React: how to load and render external html file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40108843/react-how-to-load-and-render-external-html-file)
this will solve your promblem

Comment: If you see my question i am already using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` and gone through the link that you specified. The problem is it is not reading the content in `<script>` tags. Any way thanks for pointing out the link.