# How to load external HTML file in react components?

Tags: html, reactjs

```js
import React from "react";
var htmlContent = require('../../assets/survey-chatbot-extension/index.html');

const Survey = () => {
    return (
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: htmlContent}}></div>
    )
}

export default Survey;
```

The requirement is to load the index.html file on rendering of Survey.js. This is one method using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, but it's throwing error.

[image: Here is error it's throwing]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40108843/react-how-to-load-and-render-external-html-file

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/load-external-html-into-react-comps-yi0vkk?file=/public/index.html