# Render external html file into React js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to render the html file but it seems to load only partially in the component, can someone help what am i missing? here is the codesanbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/load-external-html-into-react-comps-forked-e8xl82?file=/src/App.js
 
the script tag in the html body doesn't seem to be rendered , i tried moving it to folder and run but still doesn't work,

Any help would be really appreciated.

I tried th steps in [React: how to load and render external html file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40108843/react-how-to-load-and-render-external-html-file) but it doesnt seem to work , please check the codesanbox

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React: how to load and render external html file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40108843/react-how-to-load-and-render-external-html-file)

Comment: I tried that solution but it doesnt work, please see the attached codesanbox

Comment: @kennarddh can you check the codesanbox before closing this question as i already checked the link you had shared

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow must be self-contained, which means the [mre] and description of the problem must be in the question itself, and not rely on external links.