# Is it possible to render a HTML document that has CSS/JS inside of my React app?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, iframe

To be more specific I have a react application that will not be able to be online that will have documentation available on it.

The documentation unfortunately is either only available through their websites or for download in html format instead of pdf.

https://docs.zeek.org/en/master/

other documentation is multiple html files.

I'm not sure iframe method would work in this scenario but am struggling to find solutions to my issue.

if not possible would it be possible to simply open up the application in a new tab upon clicking a button in the react app.

Comment: In this post you can get multiple solutions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40108843/react-how-to-load-and-render-external-html-file

Answer (score 0):

You can get multiples solutions in thats link

Example:

Add html loader to your project:

```
npm i -D html-loader
```

Add the following rule to your webpack.config file:

```
{
  test: /\.(html)$/,
  use: {
    loader: 'html-loader',
    options: {
      attrs: [':data-src']
    }
  }
}
```

Import your html file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Page from './test.html';
var htmlDoc = {__html: Page};

export default class Doc extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  render(){
     return (<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={htmlDoc} />)
}}
```

**Link**

[React: how to load and render external html file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40108843/react-how-to-load-and-render-external-html-file)